# PhoneGap app plays video on background (hidden)

Tags: ios, xcode, video, cordova

I have a problem playing video using web application and phonegap. There is a link in my web app that links directly to a mp4 file. I added a handler for this type of URL in phonegap's AppDelegate class.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: 
(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType: 
(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{ 
    NSURL *url = [request URL]; 
    NSLog(@"redirect detected");
    if ([[[url path] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"mp4" ] || [[[url path] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"m4v" ] || [[[url path] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"m3u8" ]) { 
        //video files are .mp4 or m4v, stream indexes are m3u8 
        //it's a movie, go play! 
        NSLog(@"Movie detected - playing");
        NSLog([url path]);
        [self playMovieAtURL:url]; 
        return NO; 
    } else { 
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request 
                navigationType:navigationType ]; 
    } 
}
```

This works fine and the method for movie playback is called. The method is implemented like this (1):

```
-(void) playMovieAtURL: (NSURL*) theURL {
    NSLog(@"PlayMovieAtUrl");
    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie =
    [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: theURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];
}
```

also tried this (2):

```
-(void) playMovieAtURL: (NSURL*) theURL {
    NSLog(@"PlayMovieAtUrl");
    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie =
    [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: theURL];

    [theMovie setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
    [theMovie setFullscreen:YES];


    // Register for the playback finished notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver: self
     selector: @selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
     name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object: theMovie];
    NSLog(@"About to play");
    // Movie playback is asynchronous, so this method returns immediately.
    [theMovie play];
}
```

But in both cases is the player created and it plays. Only problem is, that it's HIDDEN. Sound can be heard, but no picture. The webView is still displayed. The (1) should work without any setup based on the posts elsewhere. The problem (i guess) is, that it's called in AppDelegate class and not in a Controller class. But I have no idea how to implement this using phonegap :( Any idea?

Comment: if you need more info, just let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this. Problem was, that I was not able to access the ViewController of the WebView. But I found https://gist.github.com/527494 where author uses modal window with phonegap. When I had the ViewController - it was easy :)

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController* theMovie =
    [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL: theURL];
    [super.viewController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];
```

I hope that helps someone. I took me whole day to solve it ;)